# Rewriting YAML file configuration during runtime in build pipeline using Powershell

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-devops, yaml, build-pipeline

I have a task where in I need update the configuration in the YAML file's during build pipeline. I noticed that there is a task which does this, but cant be added in the organization and also I need to update the configuration for at-least 10 yaml files.

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=jakkaj.vsts-yaml-writer&targetId=7e7d63c7-ba47-433d-affd-94b30e159ada

Can anyone guide me on this on how to achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

Here are two alternative methods:

1. Use the [Command Line task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/command-line?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) to run git command to update your yaml files.
2. Use the [Manual Validation task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/manual-validation?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) to pause the run and pop up an option box with "Resume" and "Reject", then you will recieve a notification(optional). You can update your YAML files during this time. When your work is done, click the button to resume the run.

   [image]

   [image]